# Simple encoder by a beginner

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I decided to make a quick little encoder in Python as a little challenge for myself. I decided to submit my program as I am very interested in improving my programming skills and learning better ways to code. My program simply asks for a string and for a key. The key could be +3, +4, etc. The key will add the number inputted to the number corresponding to each letter, then return the new letters.

```
dic = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5, "G": 6, "H": 7, "I": 8, "J": 9, "K": 10, "L": 11, "M": 12, "N": 13, "O": 14, "P": 15, "Q": 16, "R": 17, "S": 18, "T": 19, "U": 20, "V": 21, "W": 22, "X": 23, "Y": 24, "Z": 25, " ": 26}
dic2 = {}
for x,v in dic.items():
    dic2[v] = x

program = True

while program:
    list = []
    encodeNums = []
    encodeStr = []
    task = input("Would you like to encode or decode?: ").lower()
    if task == "encode":
        string = input("What would you like to encode?: ").upper()
        key = input("What key would you like to use?: ")
        for x in string:
            list.append(dic[x])
        for x in list:
            encodeNums.append(eval("{}{}".format(x,key)) % 27)
        for x in encodeNums:
            encodeStr.append(dic2[x])
        print("".join(encodeStr))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly suggest learning comprehensions. The simplest is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This allows you to change say:

> ```
> list = []
> for x in string:
>     list.append(dic[x])
> ```

To:

```
list = [dic[x] for x in string]
```

However, you can get better memory usage by using a generator comprehension, this works in roughly the same way as a list, however you can't index it. Which for this code is fine. To do this replace the square brackets with curved ones:

```
gen = (dic[x] for x in string)
```

You can also use a dictionary comprehension to simplify your creation of `dic2`:

```
dic2 = {v: k for k, v in dic.items()}
```

---

Purge all memory of `eval`, it leads to poor code and has severe security vulnerabilities. Instead cast the users input to an `int`. This can simplify decoding too. However you have to make sure the user does actually enter a number.

I don't like `list = []` being outside the `if` statement. There's not much of a need for this. However it's fixed when using comprehensions.

I also think you should use `while True` rather than `while program:`. As you never change `program`.

---

Merging this all together gets you:

```
dic = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5, "G": 6, "H": 7, "I": 8, "J": 9, "K": 10, "L": 11, "M": 12, "N": 13, "O": 14, "P": 15, "Q": 16, "R": 17, "S": 18, "T": 19, "U": 20, "V": 21, "W": 22, "X": 23, "Y": 24, "Z": 25, " ": 26}
dic2 = {v: k for k, v in dic.items()}

while True:
    task = input("Would you like to encode or decode?: ").lower()
    if task == "encode":
        string = input("What would you like to encode?: ").upper()
        while True:
            try:
                key = int(input("What key would you like to use?: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass
        list = (dic[x] for x in string)
        encodeNums = ((x + key) % 27 for x in list)
        encodeStr = (dic2[x] for x in encodeNums)
        print("".join(encodeStr))
```

Going forward, I'd change your code to encode and decode with the same code. This is as the Caesar cipher is a symmetric cypher, so simply using `key = -key` allows you to decode the encoding.

Allowing:

```
dic = {"A": 0, "B": 1, "C": 2, "D": 3, "E": 4, "F": 5, "G": 6, "H": 7, "I": 8, "J": 9, "K": 10, "L": 11, "M": 12, "N": 13, "O": 14, "P": 15, "Q": 16, "R": 17, "S": 18, "T": 19, "U": 20, "V": 21, "W": 22, "X": 23, "Y": 24, "Z": 25, " ": 26}
dic2 = {v: k for k, v in dic.items()}

while True:
    string = input("What would you like cypher?: ").upper()
    task = input("Would you like to encode or decode?: ").lower()
    while True:
        try:
            key = int(input("What key would you like to use?: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    if task == "decode":
        key = -key

    list = (dic[x] for x in string)
    encodeNums = ((x + key) % 27 for x in list)
    encodeStr = (dic2[x] for x in encodeNums)
    print("".join(encodeStr))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `dic` may be created more comfortably, e.g. from the string of all uppercase letters

```
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

(which is iterable) and

```
range(26)    # Generator of numbers 0, 1, ..., 25
```

First create pairs of their corresponding items using the `zip()` function:

```
zip(alphabet, range(26))
```

and then use the dict() constructor with that as its as its argument, so you will obtain:

```
dic = dict(zip(alphabet, range(26)))
```

---

Second, you use modulo `27` and number of English letters is only `26`.

---

Third, the name `list` for a list is not very descriptive for its content.

---

Fourth, the

```
eval("{}{}".format(x,key)) % 27
```

in your statement

```
encodeNums.append(eval("{}{}".format(x,key)) % 27)
```

is not only a horrible construction (it is best to avoid the `eval()` function as much as possible) but the result is not what you wanted. You wanted simply

```
(x + key ) % 26        # NOT 27
```

Comment: thanks for your advice! I decided to do modulo 27 because I also included a space " " in my dictionary. I did this to make it easier to decode the string and also to add more variety to my alphabet. Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: Oh, my fault - I didn't scroll you code enough to the right.